# Getting Json Failed error while values of json data are posting to .net web service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am posting json data to .net webservice. I am using below code.while checking in webservice it shows MessageValue:Failed.

-(void)sentSignUpDetails
{
    NSLog(@"sentSignUpDetails.......");

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"UserName\":\"%@\",\"Password\":\"%@\",\"DeviceToken\":\"%@\"}",self.emailtextfield.text,self.passwordtextfield.text,appDelegate.Devicetoken];

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://brewedlife.testshell.net/Brewedlife/AppSignup"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSLog(@"1239");
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1

{

```
 if (!data) 
  {
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data1];
  }

 else 
  {
    [data appendData:data1];
  }
```

}
It gets json failed error as below                                                           -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x15e880 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}                 Please give any idea.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your JSON request like this

> NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                             @"ValueOfUsername", @"keyOfUserName", @"ValueOfPassword", @"Password", @"ValueOfDeviceToken", @"DeviceToken",nil];
>   NSString *req = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];

If you receive an error with encoding see if this works `NSUTF8StringEncoding`